# Can the Powerapps Teams Connector instant message an individual vs posting in a channel?

Tags: microsoft-teams, connector, powerapps

I currently have a front-desk reception Powerapp that will send a Skype message to whichever employee the visitor selects from the gallery.  The employee is notified via Skype message of the visitors arrival.  I used SkypeForBusiness.SendMessage connector/function to pull this off.  Is there an equivalent in Teams, I have only seen options for posting into public channels.  At this time, do you know if the Powerapps Teams connector can send individual private messages to someone via Chat vs Channel?  Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, This is not possible with Connector or Graph APIs. You can use [Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta) or [Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors) send messages only to channels.

[Bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive) can send personal as well as channel messages.